# pretty flimsy gmail password protection

Tags: windows, windows-xp

why won't GMAIL allow me to enter my password in the password field EACH TIME I log in? All the maintenance man in my apartment complex has to do when I'm gone  is start my computer and click on the gmail icon and my account comes right up WITH THE LITTLE BALLS pretending they're hiding my password when all the repair guy has to do is click on "sign in" and BOOM -he's in my account!!. Help!!!!!

Comment: did you try to log back out?

Comment: That's not a gmail issue, as reflected in the comments above it's your browser whether that's CHROME as mentioned above, or something else (IE, Firefoxe, Safari, etc)

Comment: Maybe you should lock or log out of your computer while you're away from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the "settings" section, then "Show advanced settings" at the bottom of the page, then go into the "Privacy" section and click on the "Content Settings" button.  In there, under the "cookies" heading, put the dot in "Keep local data only until you quit your browser", it deletes all cookies that keep you logged into any site and makes you put the password in every time.